# How to check if a variable in a string is blank

Tags: go

### Want to achieve

I am building an app with Go.
It is to create a ruby file from an excel file.

If there is a value in the xx, I want to put it in the data, and if it is blank, I want to skip the process.
However, if I put nil as shown below, I get an error.

```
xx = xx + 19
if row[xx] ! = nil {
　　data["IndustryId"] = row[xx];
　　}
```

```
invalid operation: row[xx] != nil (mismatched types string and nil)
```

I hope you can help me.

### Code

test.go

```
func main() {
  excel_file, err := excelize.OpenFile("./excel/data.xlsx")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  seeds := make([]string, 0, 1000)
  seeds = append(seeds, "# Seed")
  seeds = append(seeds, "# " + time.Now().Format("RFC3339"))
  seeds = append(seeds, "")

  tpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(`test.tmpl`))

  rows, err := excel_file.GetRows("Test")
  for i, row := range rows {
    if i != 0 {

      xx := 2
      data := map[string]string{
        "Id": row[xx],
      }


      xx = xx + 19
      if row[xx] != nil {
        data["IndustryId"] = row[xx];
      }

      if err := tpl.Execute(&output, data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
      }

      seeds = append(seeds, output.String())
    }
  }

  export_file("./seeds/import_test.rb", seeds)
}
```

Comment: Compare to "" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```golang
rows, err := excel_file.GetRows("Test")
```

Here's `rows` is of type `[][]string`. Now when you do:

```golang
for i, row := range rows { ... }
```

`row` is of `[]string` and now if you index it, you'll get a string.

The zero value of a string is `""` (empty string) and not `nil`. So, please compare it with `""` instead of `nil`. Here:

```golang
row[xx] != ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. When I wrote the code as you suggested, I got an error like this: panic: runtime error: index out of range [25] with length 25. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @katahik that error means that you are using index `25` on a slice or array of length `25`. Slices and arrays are **zero-indexed**, that means that on a slice or array of length `25` you can use indexes in the range `0` to `24`. The index `25` is out-of-range. In other words, it is too large.

Comment: @katahik the panic's stack trace shows the exact file and line that causes the runtime error. If you are unable to figure it out by yourself, you should either update your original question by adding the new code and the panic's stack trace, or open a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You should Trim row[xx] to ensure that the row does not contain only space and compare it with "" not with nil.

```
import strings 
....
strings.TrimSpace(row[xx]) != ""
```